# Hide Labels with No Data in SPSS

Tags: filter, hide, spss

I just started using SPSS, there is a option of Select cases that I was trying in SPSS, and later on finding frequency based on that filter.
For Eg:
Suppose Q1 has 12 parts, Q1_1 Q1_2 Q1_3 Q1_4 Q1_5 Q1_6 Q1_7 Q1_8 Q1_9 Q1_10 Q1_11 Q1_12
I want to see data in these variables based on a condition that I used in select cases. Now when I try to see frequencies of these variables based on the filter, only 4 out of 12 satisfy has data.

Now my question is can I hide rest 8 and show only 4 with data on my output window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to describe however reading between the lines, I'm guessing you are trying to delete tables generated from FREQUENCIES which may happen to be empty (likely due to a filter applied but perhaps not necessarily either)

You could do this with SPSS Scripting but avoiding that, you may want to explore using CTABLES, which though may not be in the exact same format as FREQUENCY table output it will still none the less retrieve the same information.

Solution below. Assumes Python Integration with SPSS SELECT VARIABLES installed and of course the CTABLE add-on module.

```
/****** Simulate example data ******/.
input program.
loop #j = 1 to 100.
    compute ID=#j.
    vector Q(12).
    loop #i = 1 to 12.
      do if #j<51 and #i<9.
        compute Q(#i) = $sysmis.
      else.
        compute Q(#i) = trunc(rv.uniform(1,5)).
      end if. 
    end loop.
    end case.
end loop.
end file.
end input program.
execute.
/************************************/.

/* frequencies without filtering applied */.
freq q1 to q12.

/* frequencies WITH filtering applied */.  
/* Empty table here shoult be removed */.  
temp.
select if (ID<51).
freq q1 to q12.

spssinc select variables macroname="!Qp" /properties pattern = "^Q\d+$"/options separator="+" order=file.
spssinc select variables macroname="!Qs" /properties pattern = "^Q\d+$"/options separator=" " order=file.

temp.
select if (ID<51).
ctables /table (!Qp)[c][count colpct]
  /categories variables=!Qs empty=exclude.
```

Note if you had assess empty variables at a **total level** then there is a function in `spssaux2` (`spssaux2.FindEmptyVars`) which could help you find the empty variables and then you could build the syntax to exclude these and so contain the variables with only valid responses and then run `FREQUENCIES`. But I don't think `spssaux2.FindEmptyVars` will honor any filtering.

Comment: Thanks for providing solution to my Query, will try following it and get the desired output.

Comment: The FindEmptyVars function mentioned by Jignesh does honor any filter in effect.

Comment: I take that back: Jignesh is right.  FindEmptyVars does not honor the filter.  It's behavior is intentionally conservative to ensure that no data is lost.